# What is exemption 17347 in the context of dispatch for FAA domestic carriers?

Tags: faa-regulations, dispatch

What is exemption 17347 in the context of dispatch for FAA domestic carriers?

The explanation can be rather complicated, so I’m looking for a simple and straight forward break down.

Also, as a bonus, what is the history behind this exemption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemption 17347 was requested by the Regional Airline Association to extend a pre-existing alternate weather regulatory exemption to apply to regional airlines operating under part 121 because the FAA has changed the language referring to other carriers used in grants of exemption.

> As a separate issue, when A4A previously petitioned for this exemption, the FAA granted relief to the petitioner’s member airlines, as well as to all other “similarly situated” certificate holders, which included any air carrier operating under the provisions of part 121 (Exemption No. 3585). However, in an effort to manage exemptions granted by the FAA and to facilitate operator compliance with the conditions and limitations of a grant of exemption, the FAA is no longer including “similarly situated certificate holders” in grants of exemption.

[Regulatory Filing Source](https://www.regulations.gov/document?D=FAA-2017-0229-0004)